# Graph traversal, topologicalsort, post-visit number and pre- visit number

Tags: python, graph, depth-first-search, topological-sort

```
#Uses python3

import sys

def previsit(v, clock, pre):
    pre[v] = clock
    clock += 1
    return pre
def postvisit(v, clock, post):
    post[v] = clock
    clock += 1
    return post

def reverseg(adj):
    edges = []
    for i in range(len(adj)):
    if adj[i] != []:
        for vertex in adj[i]:
            edges.append([i, vertex])
    edgesr = [[j, i] for i, j in edges]
    adjr = [[] for _ in range(len(adj))]
    for a, b in edgesr:
        adjr[a].append(b)
    return adjr



def explore(adj, v, visited, path, clock, pre, post):
    visited[v] = True
    path.append(v)
    pre[v] = clock
    clock += 1

    for w in adj[v]:
        if (visited[w] is None):
            explore(adj, w, visited, path, clock, pre, post)

    post[v] = clock
    clock += 1


def dfs(adj, visited, clock, pre, post):
    n = len(adj)

    for v in range(n):
        if visited[v] is None:
            explore(adj, v, visited, path, clock, pre, post)








def acyclic(adj):


    visited = [None for _ in range(len(adj))]

    adjr = reverseg(adj)


    return 0


edges = [[1, 2], [2, 3], [1, 3], [3, 4], [1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 5]]
edges2 = [[], [], [], [], []]
edges1 = [[1, 2], [4, 1], [2, 3], [3, 1]]

adj = [[] for _ in range(4)]

for (a, b) in edges1:
    adj[a - 1].append(b - 1)
    #adj[b - 1].append(a - 1)
clock = 1
pre = [None for _ in range(len(adj))]
post = [None for _ in range(len(adj))]
visited = [None for _ in range(len(adj))]
path = []

#explore(adj, 0, visited, cc, ccnum)
#print(dfs(adj, visited), acyclic(adj))
v = 0
print(adj)
print(dfs(adj, visited, clock, pre, post))
print(pre)
print(post)
print(path)
```

Hi, please help check this code, I implemented the pesudocode, but the output of the previsite number and postvisited number is wrong. My task is to find the cycle in a graph, so I have to find the strongly 
connected components first, running dfs in a reversed graph, and explore the vertex with largest postnumber in the original graph.I stuck at the postnumber

Answer (score 0):

This code is based on the pesudocode, which is a depth-first-search(DFS) algorithm for graph searching, and I'm going to use it to find strongly connected components(SCC) in a graph:

```
Explore(v):
  visited(v) ← true
  previsit(v)
  for (v,w) ∈ E:
     if not visited(w):
        explore(w)
  postvisit(v)
```

and here:

```
previsit(v):
  pre(v) ← clock
  clock ← clock + 1
postvisit(v):
  post(v) ← clock
  clock ← clock + 1
```

**the clock here should be a global variable.**